# How to do this in C (from Java)

Tags: java, c

I am currently learning the wonderful Arduino and some C and I am trying to get this to work. How do I do the following in C!

```
String val = "";
while(true) {
    thisChar = "2"; // this will be a "char" in C, this is finished in C, it's reading from a stream, the "2" is just an example
    if(val.length < 3) {
        val = val + thisChar;
    } else {
        int num = val;
        // i will do something with my new int thing
        val = "";
    }
}
```

So I am trying to basically get a char, bunch three of them into a string, covert it into an int and then do something with it. the numbers sent in threes are anything between 000 and 100!

I will post what I have come up with.

```
char val[];
if (client.available() > 0) { //finns åtmminstone 1 klient?
  char thisChar = client.read(); //läser av nästa byte från servern
  if( thisChar == 'H' ){
    Serial.println("HIGH from client");
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH); // lys LED
  }
  else if( thisChar == 'L' ){
    Serial.println("LOW from client");
    digitalWrite(led, LOW); // släck LED
  }
  else {
    Serial.println(thisChar);
    int len = strlen(val);
    if(len < 3) { // saknas fortfarande tecken tex 0 eller 02
      val = val + 
    }
    else { // värdet är komplett tex 010 eller 100
      val = "";
    }
  }
}
```

**ANSWER:**
Thanks to @morgano for the chat he was able to piece together the following code from all three answers!

```
  static char val[4] = {0}; //we only care about 3 digit numbers. 
  static int len = 0; 
  //... code blabla
  char thisChar = client.read(); //läser av nästa byte från servern
  //... code blabla
  else { 
    val[len] = thisChar; 
    len++;  
    if(len > 2) { // värdet är komplett tex 010 eller 100 
      int i;
      sscanf(val, "%d", &i);
      Serial.println(i);
      //Serial.println(val);
      len = 0; 
      //val[3] = 0; 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Try something yourself before asking for a full solution!

Comment: You can use `strtol()` to parse strings into integers.

Comment: Sorry to sound untrusting, but is this actually C++ or are you stuck with C?

Comment: @KerrekSB, I believe the OP is more looking for a solution based on `realloc` or something like that.

Comment: @Diti: I don't think it's up to the OP to make such a call...

Comment: @Diti are you sure?  The way he presented the problem, I don't see a need for any dynamic allocation.

Comment: @ajb Ahh is that why nothing works, I'll try some C++ thanks for the tip

Comment: @Kerrek: Never mind, I thought the algo was about creating a string, adding characters to it, and thus would need expanding. My mistake!

Comment: @Diti that is how I would do it in Java, however the max length is three (as in when the String is filled with 3 chars it will "reset")

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks good--you just need to decide how to "append" text to your `char` array.

I would keep a variable describing the current "length" of the string.  So, you can try something like:

```
char val[4]; //we only care about 3 digit numbers. 
int valLength = 0; //No characters in the string yet.

char thisChar = client.read();

val[3] = '\0';  /* Need to terminate the string, or else... */
if (valLength < 3) {
  val[valLength] = thisChar;
  valLength++;
}
else {
  int myIntVal = strtol(val, 0, 10); //I believe this is the right syntax.  I'm not 100% sure.
  val[0] = 0;
  val[1] = 0;
  val[2] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting your Java code directly to C gives me this. Change the array size to what your max string size could be.

```
char *val;
char inputchar[10];
int num;
val= malloc(sizeof(char) *20);
while(1){
  inputchar=readclient();
  if(strlen(val) < 3)
   val = strcat(val, inputchar);
  else { 
   num= atoi(val);
   memcpy(val, '\0', 10 );
   } 
  }
 free(val);
```

You need to check the functions atoi and memcpy once.

Comment: Hello, I get this error!
WiFi.ino: In function 'void loop()':
WiFi:53: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'
WiFi:53: error: initializing argument 2 of 'char* strcat(char*, const char*)'
WiFi:53: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'char [10]'
 - i miss out the "char inputchar[10];" as I get another error

Comment: Using strcat, I had to malloc the val and free it at the end, see the edited code.

Answer (score 1):

Adding yet another solution that doesn't imply using char[] or "string" functions:

```
int val = 0;
int len = 0;

while(1) {
    char thisChar = clientread();
    if(len < 3) {
        val = val * 10 + (thisChar - 0x30);
        len++;
    } else {
        do_something_with_val(val);
        val = 0;
        len = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! I get this error: - WiFi.ino: In function 'void loop()':
WiFi:54: error: invalid operands of types 'char [10]' and 'int' to binary 'operator*'
WiFi:60: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'char [10]'

Comment: don't use `char[10]` just use `char`, this code doesn't deal with char arrays. I suspect you will need much more help... can we open a chat?

Comment: Indeed we can open a chat!

Comment: here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49613/how-to-do-this-in-c-from-java everyone else is also invited :-)